# How to store data for use in multiple data validation using GAS?

Tags: validation, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script running on Google Sheets, which brings data from another spreadsheet/file as an array and sets one of its column's data as a data validation into a cell. Then, as the user picks one option of this data validation, the script goes back to that file and brings its related data and sets it in an adjacent column and this repeats about 3 times, making the process slow.
I was wondering if that would be possible to store the first data collection into the document property and set the data validations by grabbing related information from that data set, instead of going to the other file everytime.

**Here's an update, with a working version:**

```
function listaCategorias() {
  let listaGeral = sheetBDCadProd.getRange(2, 1, sheetBDCadProd.getLastRow(), 45).getValues();//Gets all values

  //Extracts a column of interest for this first data validation setting
  let categorias = [];
  for (let a = 0; a < listaGeral.length; a++) {
    categorias.push(listaGeral[a][17])
  }
  let uniqueCat = [...new Set(categorias)]; //Gets a list of unique values. Not sure how I'd do that within new Set, so I did a for loop before
  
//Sets the data validation
  const cell = sheetVendSobEnc.getRange('B5');
  const validationCat = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(uniqueCat).setAllowInvalid(false).build();

  cell.clearContent();
  cell.clearDataValidations();
  cell.setDataValidation(validationCat);

  //Saves the data into the document property for usage in the next script/data validation
  listaGeral = JSON.stringify(listaGeral)
  PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().setProperty('listaGeral', listaGeral);
}

//This is getting one of the columns, based on the option picked..the one generated by the data validation above. 
function listaDescricao() {
  const categoria = sheetVendSobEnc.getRange('B5').getValue();
  const dadosCadProd = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().getProperty('listaGeral')
  let cadGeral = JSON.parse(dadosCadProd);
    //Filters the elements matching the option picked
  let filteredNomeSobEnc = cadGeral.filter(function (o) { return o[17] === categoria });
  //Filters unique values
  let listToApply = filteredNomeSobEnc.map(function (o) { return o[7] }).sort().reverse();
  let descUnica = listToApply.filter((v, i, a) => a.indexOf(v) === i);
  Logger.log('Descrição Única: ' + descUnica)
}
```

It's working, but I'd like to know the rooms for improvement here.

Thanks.

Comment: Sure you could store the array  into Properties Service as long as the data in it can easily be stored and recovered as a string.  When you store the array you use JSON.stringify and when you recover it you use JSON.parse() to recreate the array.

Comment: Maybe show the code so we can see if there are any obvious reasons for slow performance.

Comment: You can import data for the first use and then use a filter or query for subsequent uses. By doing so, the response will be quite immediate.

Comment: Hi, @TheWizEd! By confirming that this is possible, I'll give it a shot and will resort to this community for help, if need be. Thanks!

Comment: @santosOnit if by data validation you mean a dropdown select box have a column of check boxs for the same list.  The user checks off what they want and then have a button that runs a script that determines how many and which they want and get the data for all the selected items.  That way there are only 2 calls to getValues() the first to get the list, the second to get all the selected items.  Unless each selection is in its own/different spreadsheet.

Comment: It can be different, @TheWizEd!

Comment: @santosOnit I would need to see some example to determine if there is a some way to improve performance.  Maybe just post the script you're using now.

Comment: Hi, @TheWizEd. At this point, I'm working on defining and validating the fields, so I can implement it. I'll share it once I start working on it. Thank you!!

Comment: Hi, consider providing the relevant parts of the code you're working on.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the general workflow here. Could you provide a copy of your spreadsheet, in order to clarify this?

Comment: Hello @Iamblichus! Thanks for your request. I guess it works as fast as I expected now, consuming data from the document property, rather than going to the original file everytime for setting data validations throough the spreadsheet. I think I'll close this one. Appreciate your time!

Comment: @santosOnit If you found a solution/workaround to this, consider posting an answer explaining it. It could be useful for others with similar problems.